# Получение полного значения цвета в 16-ричном числе

Tags: html, css

Как можно получить полное шестизначное число-значение цвета? Например, есть

```
#66F
```

по правилам 16-ричных чисел, как всем известно, нули дописываются в начало, т.е

```
#00066F
```

Но нет! Совершенно другой цвет!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#66F` это тоже самое, что и `#6666FF`

`#RGB` или более глубокий цвет записывается так - `#RRGGBB`